# c++ memory release using a different pointer

Tags: c++

I have two pointers defined as following,

```
typedef float flt_array[1000];
flt_array *a_ptr; 
float *b_ptr;

a_ptr = new flt_array[200]; 
b_ptr = &a_ptr[0][0];
```

I will use `b_ptr` for the data processing.
Can I later release the memory by using

```
delete[] b_ptr;
```

I do not see any problem using g++ version
8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18.0.6) (GCC).
But not sure if there is any potential issue.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: `float*` ≠ `flt_array*`, hence **undefined behavior**.  You can fix it by `delete[] reinterpret_cast<flt_array*>(b_ptr);`.

Comment: *I do not see any problem using g++ version* -- Unfortunately, this is *not* how to determine if your code is faulty or not.  For a complex language like C++, you know the code is faulty by looking at the code, and in some cases, having to go through the C++ specification to determine if the code has issues.  You cannot simply run a program, see the program not "crash", and determine that the code is ok.

Comment: _Why_ would you want to `delete` something though a pointer of a different type?

Comment: Even if I sound like smart alec with this comment:
"R.11: Avoid calling new and delete explicitly"
That would avoid the problem completely.
https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete

Comment: Remember that one of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior is looking like everything worked.  Might not look like that tomorrow, or on a different compiler.  And if you caused some horrible corruption to C++'s memory allocator you might not notice right away.

Comment: @MarkRansom done

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and answers. I noticed in my system that the memory manager saves the size of the allocated memory in term of number of byte, not number of flt_array. That might be the reason my code did not have issue at the moment. But not sure if it is still true in other systems. I understand what I was doing is not recommended, just curious when it will get into trouble. Thanks!

Comment: Murphy's Law says you are likely to get in trouble when you provide your program to *someone else*, and they experience unexplained and intermittent crashes or data corruption.   When that *someone else* is a paying customer, you get grumpy customers - who may simply take their business elsewhere (not good for long term employment of you or your development team).   If you're lucky, you get bug reports, describing behaviours that you cannot reproduce on your development system, which makes it really difficult for developers to find (let alone, fix) the cause of the bug.

Answer (score 4):

`delete[] b_ptr;` tells the compiler to free an array of `float`s, not an array of `flt_array`s, as was actually allocated by `new flt_array[...]`. They are two different and unrelated types. `delete[]` needs to be given the original type that `new[]` returned.  `delete`'ing memory of one type via a pointer to a different type is *undefined behavior*.

Since we know via the C++ standard that the 1st element of an array shares the same starting memory address as the array itself, we know that `a_ptr` and `b_ptr` must ultimately be pointing to the same memory address in this particular example (be sure to verify that for yourself), so you can safely use `reinterpret_cast` when `delete[]`'ing `b_ptr`, eg:

```
a_ptr = new flt_array[200]; 
b_ptr = &a_ptr[0][0];
...
delete[] reinterpret_cast<flt_array*>(b_ptr);
```

Comment: This is technically also UB because array elements are not pointer-interconvertible with the array object they belong to, although they have the same address. This is intended to allow the compiler to optimize with the assumption that one can only ever reach elements of the same inner array through `&a_ptr[0][0]` and no other memory. I am not aware of any compiler actually optimizing with that assumption. `std::launder` won't help either.